# Apple Time Capsule / 802.11ac to wired network is slower than I'd expect

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, mac, wired

I've got a Macbook Pro connected to an Apple Time Capsule wirelessly. It's using 802.11ac and the detailed view of the wireless connection shows this:

[image]

The transfer speed is typically being shown in the range from 800 to 1000+ Mbits.

I've also got a Windows 10 PC plugged directly into the Time Capsule. These should be gigabit ports.

I ran a iperf3 test between these machines and these are the results:

> C:\Users\roran\Downloads\iperf-3.0.11-win64>iperf3.exe -c
>   192.168.200.5 Connecting to host 192.168.200.5, port 5201 [  4] local 192.168.200.33 port 53093 connected to 192.168.200.5 port 5201 [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth [  4]   0.00-1.00   sec 
>   27.9 MBytes   234 Mbits/sec [  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  27.1 MBytes   227 Mbits/sec [  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  26.4 MBytes   221 Mbits/sec [  4]
>   3.00-4.00   sec  25.2 MBytes   212 Mbits/sec [  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  27.2 MBytes   228 Mbits/sec [  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  25.2 MBytes   212 Mbits/sec [  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  25.8 MBytes   216 Mbits/sec [  4]
>   7.00-8.00   sec  26.4 MBytes   221 Mbits/sec [  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  28.4 MBytes   238 Mbits/sec [  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  25.8 MBytes   216 Mbits/sec
>   - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth [  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   265 MBytes   223
>   Mbits/sec                  sender [  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   265 MBytes
>   223 Mbits/sec                  receiver
>
> iperf Done.

I'm copying a large file (160gb) from the mac to the pc and I'm seeing transfer speeds inline with the results from iperf3. I'd expect that to be higher since this should be the only traffic on the network and 800 Mbytes/s (the wireless TX rate above) should be 100 MB/s.

Also, I'm seeing these odd pauses in the transfer speed where it dips down to 0 bps and then climbs back up. I think this might be on the mac side since it seems to correspond to the mac pausing for a second. Here's the perf monitor in windows:

[image]

Am I right in thinking this is a bit slow? Or, is this pretty much to be expected?

Another thing of note is that the mac is transferring from an SSD while on the  Windows PC data is going to a USB2 external drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you are using gigabit Ethernet doesn't mean your switch is capable of actually switching packets that fast.

Look for info on what to expect from your switch.  Maybe compare the speed you get with a direct crossover cable.

The performance of your hardware and software on Mac and pc should not be taken for granted either.

USB dives are not as fast as you might be expecting.  See [What's the maximum typical speed possible with a USB2.0 drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/317217/whats-the-maximum-typical-speed-possible-with-a-usb2-0-drive)

Comment: Is it safe to interpret this comment as "Your transfer speed is not entirely unreasonable"?

Comment: I think if you get better performance it won't be a lot better.  Your usb dive controller is probably the limiting factor

Comment: A very simple test shows that you're right that the USB drive / controller was a limiting factor. I'm trying copying the same file to a non-usb drive and it's about 3x faster. That's a huge difference. Enough to make me not worry about this any more. Thanks!